# Swagger/Swashbuckle error - Unable to render this definition

Tags: swashbuckle, azure-app-service-envrmnt, .net-core-2.2

.Netcore 2.2
Swashbuckle 4.0.1

Swagger UI works on localhost but after deploying to Azure ASE to site that is managed by Application Gateway, the swagger will not load. (confirmed swagger.json is generated). Error is.....

Unable to render this definition
The provided definition does not specify a valid version field.

Please indicate a valid Swagger or OpenAPI version field. Supported version fields are swagger: "2.0" and those that match  openapi: 3.0.n (for example, openapi: 3.0.0).

I have gone through other similar posts and tried others suggestions, with no resolution. Here is the applicable code from startup.

```
            app.UseStaticFiles();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseSwagger(c =>
            {
                c.RouteTemplate = "swagger/{documentName}/swagger.json";

            });
        }
        else
        {

            app.UseSwagger(c =>
            {
                c.RouteTemplate = "swagger/{documentName}/swagger.json";

                c.PreSerializeFilters.Add((doc, request) =>
                {
                    var root = request.Host.Value;
                    doc.Host = root;

                });
            });
        }
        // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.), 
        // specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "TestSwagger Api V1");
            c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
        });


        app.UseMvc();


/* from ConfigureServices */

  services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
        });
```

Comment: Did yo manage to resolve this. We are experiencing a similar problem.

Comment: I wasn't but I did pull the code and it looked like there were some package issues, maybe beta? ones. If I had the time I was going to downgrade some and rebuild to see if it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

We ran in similar issue and found that we had various version of swashbuckle nuget package, once we consolidated, it worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue just now. My application was working fine and soon, it showed me below error.

> Unable to render this definition The provided definition does not specify a valid version field.
> Please indicate a valid Swagger or OpenAPI version field. Supported version fields are swagger: "2.0" and those that match openapi: 3.0.n (for example, openapi: 3.0.0).

Previously, I had the swaggerDefinition as:

```
let swaggerDefinition = {
    swagger: "2.0.0",
    info: {
        title: "REST API's",
        description: "RESTful API for application",
        version: "1.0",
    },
    ...
}
```

When I changed the swagger version to "2.0" instead of "2.0.0" it started working. Not sure why.

Working config:

```
let swaggerDefinition = {
    swagger: "2.0",
    info: {
        title: "REST API's",
        description: "RESTful API for application",
        version: "1.0",
    },
    ...
}
```